# C# Bitcoin Address Validation [Legacy, Nested SegWit, Native SegWit] | OFFLINE

Tags: c#, bitcoin

I am looking for a class or method in c# language to validate bitcoin address.(**OFFLINE**)
I want to validate [`Legacy`, `Nested SegWit`, `Native SegWit`] [address types](https://help.crypto.com/en/articles/4056348-send-and-receive-btc-ltc-difference-between-segwit-and-legacy-address).

For this purpose i found this :
[determine-if-a-bitcoin-wallet-address-is-valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343204/determine-if-a-bitcoin-wallet-address-is-valid)
But it validates Legacy addresses only.

I also found this :
[bitcoin-address-validation](https://github.com/ruigomeseu/bitcoin-address-validation)
But i think it is using an api for this purpose & language is not c#.

I also found this :
[bitcoin-address-validator](https://github.com/kielabokkie/bitcoin-address-validator)
This is not in c# language. It's php & i am not familiar with php.

I also found this :
[address_validation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation)
Too old and only for Legacy addresses.

Please give me a solution on this.

---

Determine type of bitcoin address is not important for me.
I just want to know that a string is bitcoin address or not.

Comment: Do you need to validate checksum?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct Regex :

```
string re_path = @"^(?:[13]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}|bc1[a-z0-9]{39,59})$";
```

**Source :**
[Regex for Bitcoin Addresses](https://regexland.com/regex-bitcoin-addresses/)
***Attention :***
Address length in Base58 is not fixed. It may be as small as **26** and as big as **35** (the other answer uses wrong values)
So i corrected it in this answer

**Test :**
[Regex-Test](https://regex101.com/)